# MySQL Syntax Error: Could be in IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Need help. Having the following MySQL(version: 5.7.21) suntax error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.model, ucp.list_price,ucp.sell_price, (ucp.list_price -
>   IFNULL((SELECT (CASE WH' at line 1

for the following query:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title,n.created ucp.model,
ucp.list_price,ucp.sell_price, (ucp.list_price - IFNULL((SELECT (CASE
WHEN role_price.price='' THEN ucp.sell_price ELSE role_price.price
END) AS price FROM uc_price_per_role_prices role_price WHERE
role_price.nid=n.nid AND role_price.rid IN (2,3,4)) , ucp.sell_price )
) AS profitability, height.field_product_package_height_value,
width.field_product_package_width_value,
length.field_product_package_length_value FROM node n JOIN uc_products
ucp ON n.nid=ucp.nid JOIN field_data_field_product_package_height
height ON n.nid=height.entity_id JOIN
field_data_field_product_package_width width ON n.nid=width.entity_id
JOIN field_data_field_product_package_length length ON
n.nid=length.entity_id WHERE n.status =1 AND n.nid NOT IN   (2298,2299,2300,2301,2302,2303,2304,2305,2307,2308,2309,2310,2311,2312,2313,2
314,13963,13964)
AND height.field_product_package_height_value !='' AND
width.field_product_package_width_value !='' AND
length.field_product_package_length_value !='' GROUP BY n.nid ORDER BY
n.created DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: It's most likely before the IFNULL; MySQL errors tend reference where the problem started.

Comment: You’re missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one extra closing bracket )

```
IFNULL((SELECT (CASE WHEN role_price.price='' THEN ucp.sell_price 
ELSE role_price.price END) AS price FROM uc_price_per_role_prices role_price
WHERE role_price.nid=n.nid AND role_price.rid 
IN (2,3,4), ucp.sell_price ) ) AS profitability
```